# What compression algorithms or image formats are supported in the gdal_retile.py -co "COMPRESS=" argument?

Tags: python, geoserver, gdal

Running Ubuntu 14.04 with GeoServer 2.7.2. I've got gdal-bin 1.10.1 libgdal1h 1.10.1 and python-gdal 1.10.1 installed from the default repository.

I'm using gdal_retile.py to create an image pyramid which is then hosted on geoserver. I'd prefer to use PNG but it doesn't appear to be supported.

So far I've found:

-co "COMPRESS=JPEG"
-co "COMPRESS=LZW"

```
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 7 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -targetDir ./kenai translated/*.TIF
```

What compression algorithms or image formats are supported in the gdal_retile.py "COMPRESS=" argument?

Comment: The compression method that is used in png is "deflate". Supported methods are driver specific and for GeoTIFF you need to read GDAL GeoTIFF documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The creation options you are able to use with the `-co` option solely depend on the image format you want to use.

GeoTiff for instance supports the following compression algorithms: JPEG/LZW/PACKBITS/DEFLATE/CCITTRLE/CCITTFAX3/CCITTFAX4/LZMA/NONE.

Each GDAL driver has it's own page where all the creation options are listed. Here is the [GeoTiff driver page](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html)